Java Spring Data JPA unable to fetch associated table data
I have the following entity classes,
Where an AppUser can have 1 Profile and multiple Post,
1 Post can be associated with only 1 AppUser,
AppUser and Role will be many to many association.
ERD -

AppUser - 

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "app_user")
public class AppUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "profile_id")
    private Profile profile;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "appUser", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
}


Profile -

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "profile")
public class Profile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String bio;
}


Post -

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "post")
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String content;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "app_user_id")
    private AppUser appUser;
}


Role -

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "role")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<AppUser> appUsers = new HashSet<>();
}

I get the following response, where Role data is not being fetched,when I do a simple userRepository.findAll();
// http://localhost:8080/user/all

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "username": "john_doe",
    "email": "john@gmail.com",
    "profile": {
      "id": 1,
      "bio": "This is John Doe's bio."
    },
    "posts": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "content": "Content of post 1"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "content": "Content of post 2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "username": "jane_smith",
    "email": "jane@gmail.com",
    "profile": {
      "id": 2,
      "bio": "This is Jane Smith's bio."
    },
    "posts": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "content": "Content of post 3"
      }
    ]
  }
]


Have you put the value in @JsonManagedReference(value = "something") and tried to see if it works?

What is /user/all retrieving? What endpoint is this pointing to?

Getters and Setters are missing in the classes Post and Profile. This is needed for Jackson serialization to work. Otherwise you will get just empty JSON.

updated the question, thanks the Getters and Setters were missing in the classes Post and Profile entities, now just the Role data is missing

You need to use @JsonManagedReference for the roles field in the AppUser entity and @JsonBackReference for the appUsers field in the Role entity. And most likely you also need to use @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "roles") when loading users to avoid LazyInitializationException, or you can just add fetch = FetchType.EAGER for the roles field.

fetch = FetchType.EAGER for the roles field in AppUser entity class? like @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

@Dev1ce yes, in the @ManyToMany annotation

thanks it worked, do you see any other improvements to the entities?

@Dev1ce There is no point in using List in a posts field without the @OrderBy annotation.
